# How to do orderby query on PostgreSQL table using FASTApi?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I write a query to select the top 5 rows with the highest upvote count?

Code Snippet:

```
@app.get("/leaderboard/org/", response_model=User, status_code= status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_leaderboard_org(skip: int=0,take: int= 5):
    query = user_details.select().offset(skip).limit(take)
    return await database.fetch_all(query)

@app.get("/leaderboard/org/", response_model=User, status_code= status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_leaderboard_org(skip: int=0,take: int= 5):
    query = user_details.select().offset(skip).limit(take)
    return await database.fetch_all(query)
```

Following are my table base table details

```
Table:
id   Name             Org_Name Upvote
1    Sejal Mohata        EBIA   10
2    Jayne                IT    5
3    Rakesh Nerkar       EBIA   2
4    Howard Elias        PCF    9
5    Dinesh Khatter       IT    6
6    Ishan Rez          VMWare  15
7    Uvi Rocker           PCF   4
```

Expected Output for /leaderboard/ind:

```
id   Name             Upvote
6    Ishan Rez        15
1    Sejal Mohata     10
4    Howard Elias     9
5    Dinesh Khatter   6
2    Jayne            5
```

Expected Output for /leaderboard/org:

```
id   Org         Upvote
1.   VMWare       15
2.    PCF         13
3.   EBIA         12
4.    IT          11
```

Comment: *with the highest upvote count* Upvote count? On Stack Overflow or what?

Comment: with the highest upvote count in the table

Comment: Show more of your code.  What is `user_details`?  You will need a `org_summary` for selecting a `sum` of `upvote` aggregate over the `org` group

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.order_by` and `desc`

```
query = user_details
  .select()
  .order_by(
     desc(user_details.Upvote)
   )
  .offset(skip)
  .limit(take)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'desc' is not defined
It throws this error

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import desc` or `user_details.Upvote.desc()`